Deduce Conditional Independence based on Joint Density Factorization
Given an arbitrary factorization of the joint density function, how do we systematically determine the minimal set of pairwise conditional independence relations that would satisfy the factorization?
By minimal, I mean a set with the least number of constraints such as $X \perp Y | Z$ where $X,Y,Z$ are random variables.
Here's a more concrete example that I am working on. The goal is to find the minimal set of pairwise independence relations. Assume all random variables here are discrete and the joint mass function is given by
$$p_{M,N,T,X,Y,Z}(m,n,t,x,y,z) = p_{X|Z}(x|z) \cdot p_{M,N}(m,n)\cdot p_{T,Y|N}(t,y|n) \cdot p_{Z|M, T}(z|m, t)$$
Based on this factorization, the minimal set I found is:

$X \perp M, N, T, Y | Z$
$Z \perp N, Y | M, W$

However, I have no way of proving if this is sufficient or minimal. I got to this through trial and error, so a more systematic approach would be desirable.
